# Background Image keeps getting cut off at the bottom

Tags: html, css

Here is the link to my codepen page with the code.  As you can see the Jumbotron background image keeps getting cut off at the bottom and I cant seem to fix this.

http://cdpn.io/onKzF

Comment: This is not a question.

Comment: Looks like your css .jumbotron is missing a height. Try this for a start: height: 437px;

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for posting your code, but please put a little more description in your question: what problem are you having, what is the result you expect, and [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) so far? Going through the [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) will help us better answer your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As earlier mentioned, try this on your CSS:

```
.jumbotron {
    background: url("http://i1244.photobucket.com/albums/gg572/fitnessbeast1/Jumbotron/Tron.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 / cover rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0 15px;
    width: 90%;
    height: 437px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your image is much bigger than the div, try setting a height. You may want to look into the sliding door technique, as well.

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/perfect-css-sprite-sliding-doors-button/

Answer (score 0):

Just add height to your **.jumbotron** class

```
.jumbotron{height:371px}
```

or add content to the **jumbotron** container

```
<div class="jumbotron">
      <h2>Jumbotron</h2>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of 
    </div>
```